# Pushing values into Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble receiving the values I am pushing into my cards array. I don't know if it is that I am not calling the right property or I am just not adding into the array correctly.

```
<?php

class Deck{

    public function __construct(){
        $values =array('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A');
        $suits =array('Diamond','Club','Heart','Spade');
        $cards = array();
        foreach ($suits as $suit) {
            foreach($values as $value){
                $cards[] = "$value of $suit's";
            }
        }
    }
}

$deck = new Deck();
var_dump($deck);
```

Comment: You have a single quote in  $cards[] = "$value of $suit's";   .. is a typo?

Comment: $cards[] = $value." of ".$suits;

Comment: `$deck` is your object. Inside your constructor you have a local variable `$cards` holding your created array. Just do `print_r($cards);` inside the constructor?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$cards` is a variable local to `__construct`: once that function ends, that variable evaporates. Instead, you probably want to make `cards` a member of the class:

```
class Deck {
    public $cards = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $values =array('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A');
        $suits =array('Diamond','Club','Heart','Spade');
        $cards = array();
        foreach ($suits as $suit) {
            foreach($values as $value){
                $this->cards[] = "$value of $suit's";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `$this->cards` inside the object, or `$deck->cards` outside.

Comment: and then do var_dump($deck->cards); ?